# Pig group by two fields yields strange result

Tags: apache-pig

I have a problem grouping data with apache-pig.

Loading data with:

```
client_trace_send = LOAD '/user/hduser1/adm_project/client_trace50.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (code:chararray, client_id:int, loc_ts:int, length:int, op:chararray, err_code:int, time:long, thread_id:INT);
```

Limitting and checking data:

```
client_trace_send_small = LIMIT client_trace_send 10;
DUMP client_trace_send_small;
```

Data loaded:

```
(msg_snd,0,1,46,enrol_req,-1,1414250523591,9)
(res_rcv,0,1,25,enrol_resp,,1414250523655,9)
(msg_snd,1,2,48,query_queue,-1,1414250523655,9)
(res_rcv,1,2,14,err,19,1414250523661,9)
(msg_snd,1,3,59,peek_req,-1,1414250523661,9)
(res_rcv,1,3,13,err,0,1414250523662,9)
(msg_snd,1,4,59,peek_req,-1,1414250523662,9)
(res_rcv,1,4,13,err,0,1414250523663,9)
(msg_snd,1,5,59,peek_req,-1,1414250523663,9)
```

Now, i want to group said data over the fields "client_id" and "loc_ts".

```
GROUPED = GROUP client_trace_send_small by (client_id,loc_ts);
```

Check the result:

```
DUMP GROUPED;
```

And its strange:

```
((0,1),{(msg_snd,0,1,46,enrol_req,-1,1414250523591,9)})
((1,2),{(msg_snd,1,2,48,query_queue,-1,1414250523655,9)})
((1,3),{(msg_snd,1,3,59,peek_req,-1,1414250523661,9)})
((1,4),{(msg_snd,1,4,59,peek_req,-1,1414250523662,9)})
((1,5),{(msg_snd,1,5,59,peek_req,-1,1414250523663,9)})
((8,28493),{(msg_snd,8,28493,62,pop_req,-1,1414251764157,16)})
((9,25976),{(msg_snd,9,25976,66,query_sender,-1,1414251764148,17)})
((19,28250),{(msg_snd,19,28250,64,pop_req,-1,1414251764152,27)})
((31,27977),{(msg_snd,31,27977,65,peek_req,-1,1414251764152,39)})
```

There are values present which dont even appear in the loaded data. 
For the first group I would expect something like:

```
((0,1),{(msg_snd,0,1,46,enrol_req,-1,1414250523591,9),{(res_rcv,0,1,25,enrol_resp,,1414250523655,9)})
```

What is going wrong here?

I appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Best regards

Comment: you dumped `client_trace_send_small` and grouped `send_small` !

Comment: Ooops excuse me, that is a copy & paste error. I did in fact group client_trace_send_small. Otherwise I would have received an error in the grunt console as send_small does not exist.

Comment: Edit your question please, so it can understandable for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [LIMIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#LIMIT) take a random set of data:

> There is no guarantee which tuples will be returned, and the tuples
>   that are returned can change from one run to the next.

And because there is two `DUMP` in your scipt, therefore Pig will split the pipeline into two pipelines, each one execute `LIMIT` separately. Therefore you will get two different datasets for each sub-pipeline.

But all what we are sure about, is that dumped data are obviously from the input file and they are coming from maximum of 10 lines (<10 if the file has less lines).

You can check your [explain](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/test.html#explain) plan and it's [explanation](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch07.html).

Comment: Oh shame. Thanks a lot!